# Does this latch have a name?

Tags: digital-logic, terminology, latching

I'm looking for a circuit like:

[image]

Where, on the rising edge of any input, the corresponding output latches on and the rest of the outputs turn off. Sort of a mutually exclusive selection latch.

Does this type of circuit have a name?

I can't find any results in my searches because I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: Most logic circuits do not have names. Basically anything that does not have a name is custom.

Comment: @DKNguyen So this would be a custom circuit, then, rather than something I might find an off-the-shelf chip for?

Comment: Yes. Your circuit is probably best built centered around a digital demultiplexer (or an analog mux/switch where direction doesn't matter). Possibly including a priority decoder with some flip-flops for the pulse-sensitive behaviour. Or program a small MCU.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ok thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this type of circuit have a name?

Yes.  This is called a "radio button" circuit, because it acts as the pushbutton tuning mechanism of an old car radio.  Search for that and you will get many schematics.  There is no single logic chip that does this, although it would be a relatively small program for a microcontroller.

It is different from a "game show" circuit, which has two extra layers of logic functions.  With a game show circuit, pressing any button latches its output and locks out all of the other buttons.  The circuit is frozen in that state until the Reset input is activated.

Answer (score 3):

I believe a *bus arbiter* might work in your situation, but they don't appear to be widely available and the truth table doesn't explicitly state what happens if the input signal is removed and no other inputs are present.  You might have to add a latch, which puts you into "just use a microprocessor" territory.

Example: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NXP%20PDFs/74F786.pdf

[image: truth table]